# Did the Soyuz 1 mission fail because of an ignored decimal point?

Tags: history, space-flight

I am from an Eastern bloc nation. In my childhood I was taught that the [Soyuz 1 mission](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soyuz_1) failed because a decimal point was ignored during the pre-flight check, which was the cause of the [parachute failure](http://www.spacesafetymagazine.com/space-disasters/soyuz-1/).

Sources are abundant in my native language referencing this teaching. Yet I am unable to find any information relating to a decimal point being the cause of failure in the English language.

Did the Soyuz 1 mission fail because of an ignored decimal point?

Comment: This is missing a notable claim, possibly because they are all in Russian or other Eastern bloc languages.  Please quote one, with attribution and citation, preferably with an English translation added to the original (which presumably would be in your native language).

Comment: Neither your first nor your second link say anything at all about decimal point.

Comment: @CommonGuy: That's part of the premise of the question, as both linked sources are in English and the OP is currently not finding any mention of decimal points in English articles on the subject.

Comment: @Flater Ok, but then I would expect a link with such a mention in another language to prove that it is not an OP's own invention. BTW Russian Wikipedia also does not mention ignored decimal point as probable cause of failure.

Comment: I'd imagine you'd struggle to find any first-hand English documents regarding Soyuz 1.  Any English documents that exist are almost certainly translated from or summaries of Russian documents.